# Yii2 calculate field data before validation

Tags: php, yii2

My model contains field "authorname" which has to substituted with the current user login before form validation when creating records.

Ok, I wrote in appropriate controller:

```
public function beforeValidate() {
    if($this->isNewRecord) {
        $this->authorname = Yii::$app->user->identity->username;
    }
    return parent::beforeValidate();
}
```

It works - no need to show calculated field in form, substituion works good.

EXCEPT one unpleasant thing - search string above data grid also has $this->isNewRecord = true and filters whole data array by username. 
How to enforce Yii2 do not evaluate search record as the new record?
Or how to write beforeValidate() function to get the difference between really inserted data and virtually inserted search row?

Comment: Why don't you set default value for `authorname` to current username in rules? Easier than `beforeValidate()`. I don't know your usecase but simpler i guess.

Comment: You should use beforeSave instead of beforeValidate.

Comment: @nicolascolman That's wrong - empty field blocks validation before saving. Thus, rewrite beforeSave - too late.

Comment: Then you have to use scenarios and create a new class for seaching.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remove the line from the SearchModel:

```
andFilterWhere(['like', 'authorname', $this-> authorname])
```

or

```
'authorname' => $this->authorname,
```

Comment: Not 100% but enough in my case